# Rewriting _version metadata from elasticsearch field using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using the ELK- Stack to import CSV files. Each time the CSV files are imported the "_version" field of a document increases, which is as expected. However, because the _version field is a metadata field, is not indexed by ELK. Therefore the field is not searchable and cannot be used in the Dashboard.

I've created a second logstash configuration where both the input as well as the output are Elasticsearch.

Filter configuration:

```
filter {
mutate {
   add_field => {"Version" => "{[@metadata][_version]}"}
 }
}
```

Input configuration:

```
input {
elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  index => "test_csv"
  query => '{"query":{"match_all" : {}}}'
  size => 1000
  scroll => "1s"
  docinfo => true
  docinfo_fields => ["_index", "_type", "_id", "_version"]
  schedule => "/1 * * * *" 
}
}
```

I cannot get the value from the _version field. The Output in Kibana looks like:

```
Version         {[@metadata][_version]}
```

If I replace the _version field in the filter with _id or _index I get information back.

Any ideas on how to get value out of the _version field? Any thoughts on the matter are highly appreciated.

Chloe

Answer (score 0):

For version 6.4.2, following works for me:

```
filter {
     mutate {  
         add_field => {"Version" => "%{[@version]}"} 
     }
}
```